# Text index in mongo and sort operation

Tags: mongodb, sorting, indexing

Reading the mongo documentation you can read in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#restrictions the following:

> "Sort operations cannot obtain sort order from a text index, even from a compound text index; i.e. sort operations cannot use the ordering in the text index."

Having that note in mind I will use a mongo client in order to do some test.

First I will create a text index:

`db.collection.createIndex( { "product.title": "text" } )`

Then I will try to find some data using the index text and apply some sort in the result :

`db.collection.find( { $text: { $search: "SAR" } } ,{"product.title":1}).sort({"product.title":1})`

That query return the following:

`{"product" : { "title" : "SAR 1" } } 
{"product" : { "title" : "SAR 2" } } 
{"product" : { "title" : "SAR 3" } }`

then when I change the order sort:

`db.collection.find( { $text: { $search: "SAR" } } ,{"product.title":1}).sort({"product.title":-1})`

The result change:

`{ "product" : { "title" : "SAR 3" } } 
{ "product" : { "title" : "SAR 2" } } 
{ "product" : { "title" : "SAR 1" } }`

So, I can use the text index and use the sort (the documentation says that you cannot)

What is the goal of the text index and sort restriction? I sure that I don't understand the restriction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run that query through the [MongoDB explainer](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/), it will tell you for certain what is happening; but my guess is this:

- Your *query* is using the text index, no problem. That's just the bit which finds which documents to return
- But when it comes to *sorting* those documents, the database server is having to do that *without the assistance of any indexes*

In your example, with only a very small number of documents returned by the query, the sorting will not take very long. But a different query, perhaps an aggregation which has a stage where it must sort many thousands of documents, would be slow because of the unassisted sorting.

Comment: Thanks! For you answer, was very useful. Now I understand a bit more, I will check the 'explainer' that you mentioned